# AJAX get from another domain (Dropbox)

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I'm writing a simple PDF newsletter reader where, for the sake of simplicity, the files and feed are hosted on a Dropbox public folder. I'm doing it this way so the people who write the newsletter can update the files and feed without the need of a webmaster.

The problem I'm having is, when I try to pull the feed (atom) from Dropbox I'm getting a cross-domain error.

I understand the purpose behind blocking cross scripting requests but it is it possible to create a non-server-side workaround and/or exception for this one file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should use a JSONP approach on this:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Don't store the feed on Dropbox, store a JSON file and work with it.

Comment: Damn... That's the message I've been getting form searching Google and SO. I guess I'll have to try a JSON feed. Too bad there's no formal json-atom specification yet.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, there's no way to do this because of all the security concerns, which also varies for different browsers. Using your server to make a single point of contact is usually the best way if you can stretch to doing that.